# Testing classes that make use of Spring 5 WebClient

Tags: spring, mockito, spring-webflux, wiremock

We're slowly migrating some projects from using the legacy RestTemplate class to the new Spring 5 WebClient. As part of this, we have some existing test classes that make use of Mockito to verify that a given method will reach out to make a GET/POST/whatever to endpoint X using the template.

Given the fluent interface of the WebClient, the same mocking approach isn't really practical. I have spent some time using WireMock, which is great, but unfortunately there seems to be a bug where occasionally the WireMock tests will overrun or hang, and as such I'm considering alternatives.

Does anyone have any other suggestions for frameworks or techniques to use to verify that Spring's WebClient is making expected calls as part of SUT execution?

Comment: Do you know what the bug actually is? Are you sure it is the Wiremock itself? Because it's a good tool for your case, IMHO.

Comment: I write tests, for the APIs I write, using Mockito and the WebClient and I dont see any problem with that. Why dont you use mockito instead?

Comment: @uneq95 - do you use enable deep stubbing? From my initial tries with Mockito, it seemed not to play well with the fluent interface of WebClient.

Comment: @f1dave I did not use deep studding and I don't even know what it is.

Comment: @uneq95 perhaps provide a code sample of what you do to stub as an answer to this question, as that may help myself and others with the same question.

Answer (score 6):

Spring actually uses [OkHttp MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) for testing of the WebClient.

[Spring's Example Integration Tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientIntegrationTests.java)

You can set up ordered mock responses or map mock responses to request details.

Answer (score 0):

#### Approach 1 (preferred)

[MockWebServer](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mocking-webclient) sounds like a cool approach(i.e Use `WebClient` for real, but mock the service it calls by using `MockWebServer` (`okhttp`)). An adapted example is:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class serviceImplTest {

    private ServiceImpl serviceImpl;
    public static MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() throws IOException {
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        mockWebServer.start();
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    static void tearDown() throws IOException {
        mockWebServer.shutdown();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        String baseUrl = String.format("http://localhost:%s", mockWebServer.getPort());
        serviceImpl = new ServiceImpl(WebClient.builder(), baseUrl);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("whatever")
    void methodName() {
        mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().addHeader("header", "abcde123")); //MockWebServer will respond with the queued stub.
        String header = serviceImpl.fetchHeader();
        assertThat(header).isEqualTo("abcde123");
    }
}
```

#### Approach 2

I have also tried the other approach, i.e **Use `Mockito` to mimic the behavior of WebClient**, and it's working fine. The only *downside* is that there is a lot of `given()-willReturn()`, to cater for each call in the chain(of the fluent `WebClient` API).

Comment: Indeed it is where you make the HTTP call. I don't quite understand what do you mean by *other necessary parameters*, but when you construct an object, the constructor should ideally contain 2 or 3 params, at the most. If there is more, it's probably an indicator that you should refactor your class into smaller classes.

Comment: thanks for reply. what about if we write Unit Test for a service method that calls WebClient method? This approach works when directly testing WebClient method, but when testing another method that calls WebClient method, it fails. So, would you consider to add an example for that? Thanks in advance.